# Akka Streams - Stream Large Table

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

How can I stream all the rows from a large table using Akka Streams?

I need to stream some data out of a relational DB. In some cases, I get a large list of IDs. In other cases, I need to stream out the whole table, up to 1e9 rows. I have a working solution for the case where I have a (large) list of PK IDs (see below). I split the list of IDs into 1000-element batches, select one batch at a time and return the data. But this does not work for the cases where I need to stream the whole table, when I don't have a list of PK IDs. I am thinking of

1. select min(pk_id), max((pk_id) from my_table
2. split the interval (min_id, max_id) into N batches such that the size of each batch < S
3. use the solution below to stream one such batch at a time

But this seems complicated. Are there any better designs?
(This is my first Akka Streams project.)

```
import java.sql.Connection    
import akka.stream.stage.{AbstractOutHandler, GraphStage, GraphStageLogic}
import akka.stream.{Attributes, Outlet, SourceShape}
import com.typesafe.config.Config    
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.util.control.NonFatal

class DbSource(tableName: String, abc: String) extends GraphStage[SourceShape[String]] {
  private val baseQry: String = query(tableName, abc)
  private val jdbc: Config = appConfig.config.getConfig("jdbc")
  private implicit val conn: Connection = ...
  private var batchID = 0
  private var numRows = 0
  private val batches: Seq[Seq[Long]] = idBatches(tableName, idName, pkIDs)

  val out: Outlet[String] = Outlet.create(s"$tableName.out")

  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic = {
    new GraphStageLogic(shape) {
      setHandler(out, new AbstractOutHandler() {
        override def onPull(): Unit = {
          maybeSomeBatch.map(extractBatch).foreach(msg => push(out, msg))
        }
      })
    }
  }

  private def maybeSomeBatch: Option[Seq[Long]] = {
    if (batchID < batches.size) {
      batchID += 1
      Some(batches(batchID - 1)) // because we have already incremented it
    } else None
  }

  override val shape: SourceShape[String] = SourceShape.of(out)

  private def extractBatch(batch: Seq[Long]): String = {
      // select from table where ID in batch
      // package the data and return as a string
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there an Alpakka connector available for your database?  The Slick JDBC connector can be used to connect to any JDBC database.  https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/index.html

Comment: There is, but my result sets are not convenient to model with case classes (as Slick wants me to). The point here is: how do I chop up "select * from one_billion_rows" so that I can serve it in chunks? I have already figured out how to stream when I have well defined chunks. But there are no natural ways to create chunks when there's no WHERE clause.

Comment: Rather than providing a ID sequences and using `SELECT ... WHERE id IN <seq>` in the query, wouldn't it be easier to provide ID ranges and query with `SELECT ... ORDER BY id LIMIT <rowsPerBatch> <offset>`?